# Hide items from GridView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I tried to hide some items in my GridView dynamically with this code:

```
public class GridHelper extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
{
    private Context context; 
    private int layoutResourceId;    

    private ArrayList<Object> mainlist = null;
    private ArrayList<Object> sichtbar = null;

    public GridHelper(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Object> mainlist) 
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, mainlist);

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;

        this.mainlist = mainlist;
        this.sichtbar = ArrayList<Object>(); 
        // that's important otherwith the items are doublicated but the items 
        // are inside the List. I think the add method is called somewhere 
        // in the super constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null)
        {           
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            Object t = sichtbar.get(position);

            if(t != null)
           {
                row = (View) t;
           }
        }

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return sichtbar.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object)
    {
        super.add(object);
        sichtbar.add(object);
    }

    public void show(int pos)
    {
        if(sichtbar.contains(mainlist.get(pos)) == false)
        {
            sichtbar.add(mainlist.get(pos));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void hide(int pos)
    {
        if(sichtbar.contains(mainlist.get(pos)) == true)
        {
            sichtbar.remove(mainlist.get(pos)); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

But the search function does not work. The list has the right size after my show/hide method but the first item (`mainlist .get(0)`) is allways visible and I think it covered the right item. I found out that the `getView` method is allways called one time more than the size of the list. If the list has 3 items the `getView` method is called 4 times and so on.

The seconde thing is: If I have 3 items in my GridView and call the hide function for two items the `getView` methode is called 4 times (the old size + 1) and than again 2 times (new size + 1). That is very strange isn't it?

Why is that? I think the logic behind it is right isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first item is always visible (and you can see getCount first items( because inside your `getView` you are always returning the first element.

to me seems that your sichtbar contains Views instance you want to show inside your GridView. If you have already inflated this elements, imo, your getView should looks like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        row = (sichtbar.get(position) != null) ? (View)sichtbar.get(position) : row;
        return row;
    }
```

> The seconde thing is: If I have 3 items in my GridView and call the
>   hide function for two items the getView methode is called 4 times (the
>   old size + 1) and than again 2 times (new size + 1). That is very
>   strange isn't it?

there is no guarantee on the number the getView callback will be invoked

Comment: Thank you that answer is great! Works like a charm now :) But I do not understand why I have allways returned the first element. I thought I do this with `Object t = sichtbar.get(position)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is to maintain 2 separate Lists in your adapter. One contains all the items, and the other one contains only the visible ones. Or one contains the visible items and the other one the invisible ones. Both is possible. Remember that `getCount()` has to return the number of items that are visible.

Comment: okay thanks for that. I tried to do so but it does not work right now. I updated my question with new findings. Can you please have a look on it?

Comment: First of all, it should not matter how often `getView()` is called. I think it can happen that it gets called more than once with the same position parameter. Secondly, do not save the View object in your visible list. That will end in chaos because `ListView` will recycle the Views. Save the data objects instead. I guess at the beginning, all the items are visible, so you can initialize the visible list with `this.sichtbar = ArrayList<Object>(mainlist);` and from there remove the ones that you want to hide.

Comment: I thought that it is a good idea that I store the View Objects in my adapter. I have many objects which all extands a LinearLayout but all with different XML layouts. In the constructor of this objects I load the XML Layout which is exactly fot the objects so I can add all different objects with one ArrayAdapter and do not have to write more than one. Isn't that a good idea?

Comment: A `ListView` handles a lot of the child View management for you - like the re-using of Views that are not visible anymore. You basically want to remove all this functionality and use it in a way that it was not intended to. Maybe you should consider to use another layout for that. A `LinearLayout` for example. But this really depends on your exact use case.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that but it's reasonable. What do you mean with _maybe you should consider to use another layout for that. A LinearLayout for example_? How can a LinearLayout be a solution for that?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bunch of different items that you want to display in a list. All the items use different layouts, but are fairly pre-defined. A ListView usually uses the same layout for all its items. A LinearLayout on the other hand does not use an Adapter, so you can just add whatever Views you want. More information about layouts here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Ah now I understand waht you mean. Okay it is easy to "create a ListView" with a LinearLayout but a GridView is more compleex I think. Maybe I can try with a TableLayout. I have to think about that but thank you for this food for thought.